# Count one column by considering another column

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my Audit table:

```
id      productnr    invoicenr         price              
1         2            1000             20
2         2            1000             20
3         31           1000             25
4         23           1001             15
5         23           1002             15
6         71           1002             27
7         2            1003             20
```

I need to write 2 different queries and I have no idea how should I write them:

1. How many invoices do have ONLY product 2 (+ Total price)?
2. How many invoices do have diffrent products but product 2 as well (+ Total price)?

the result I want looks like this:

```
Count    totalPrice
1250       206030
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show the results that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(case when num_products = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as has_2_only,
       sum(case when num_products = 1 then total else 0 end) as has_2_total,
       count(*) as has_2,
       sum(total) as has_2_total
from (select invoicenr, sum(price) as total,
             count(distinct product_nr) as num_products,
             max(case when product = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as has_product_2
      from t
      group by invoicenr
     ) i
where has_product_2 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I just have a small question. What is wanna know the exact query with 2 product2? I mean: How many invoices do have ONLY product 2 AND product 3  (+ Total price)?

Comment: @Rezu . . . That would be a different question.  But just add another condition for `has_product_3` and use that for logic.